# mysql_field_table equivalent for mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

What's the equivalent of the following functions for mysqli:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->link_id, $sql);
$k = 0;

mysql_field_table($result, $k)
mysql_field_name
mysql_field_type
mysql_field_len
mysql_field_flags
```

I have a function that queries database tables and displays table information such as name, type, flags and length. Now I need to convert it into mysqli

Comment: -1 for not RTFMing: http://php.net/mysqli

Answer (score 4):

mysqli_result has all of those functions you need:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Answer (score 2):

The function that you are looking for is `mysqli_fetch_field_direct`, this return an object with all the value that you are looking for on your case,

here is the example:

```
$table_info = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $k);
$lenght = $table_info->length;
$name = $table_info->name;
$type = $table_info->type;
$flag = $table_info->flags;
```

This is should be enough.

Here is the full description on the php documentation website:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php